# Unwanted blank page generated by macro

Tags: blank-page

That code generate unwanted blank page before image. I dont undestand why and how. Can anybody explain how to get rid that blank page?

```
\newcommandx{\spic}[3][1=0,2]{
    \clearpage
    \begin{minipage}[t][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
    \center{\includegraphics[angle=#1, width=\textwidth]{#3}}
    %\caption*{#2}
    \end{minipage}
    \clearpage
}

\spic{_SDC7912}
```

Comment: the minipage is too large to fit on a page you presumably had warnings about overfull boxes? (but hard to debug if you do not provide a test document) also note `\center` is the internal definition of `\begin{center}` you should use `\centering` (and they do not take an argument, so `\centering \includegraphics...` without the `{}`

Comment: Thanks, \dimexpr\textheight-6pt\relax helps.